# Eclipse Java Loops Dice Roll to Get Doubles and show how many times it ran

Tags: java, loops

I need to make a program that: Repeatedly roll 3 dice until doubles are rolled (any two are the same).  Show the values each time and afterwards state how many tries it took to get doubles.

The problem is that is runs forever, and it doesn't accurately tell me how many times it ran.

Here is what I have so far.

```
public class ExtraProblem4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int first, second, third;
        int counter = 0;
        while(true) {
            counter ++;

            first = (int)(Math.random()*(6-1+1)+1);
            second = (int)(Math.random()*(6-1+1)+1);
            third = (int)(Math.random()*(6-1+1)+1);

            System.out.println(first + "\t" + second + "\t" + third + "\t");

            if (first == second || second == third || first == third) {
                System.out.println("Double! It took " + counter + " tries to get it!");
            }
            else {
                first = (int)(Math.random()*(6-1+1)+1);
                second = (int)(Math.random()*(6-1+1)+1);
                third = (int)(Math.random()*(6-1+1)+1);

                System.out.println(first + "\t" + second + "\t" + third + "\t");
            }
        }   

    }
```

Comment: `"The problem is that is runs forever..."` -- this: `while (true)` may have a little to do with this.

Comment: I think you may be better off taking out that entire `else` block.  It's not doing anything you aren't already doing.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using a do-while instead.. also I got rid of some redundant lines of code, like the else in the if.

```
public class ExtraProblem4 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int first, second, third;
        int counter = 0;
        boolean rolledDoubles; //initializes boolean variable to keep the loop going
        do //use a do-while so it tests after each roll
        {
            rolledDoubles = false; //defines variable as false so it keeps looping
            counter = counter + 1; // more reliable step

            first = (int)(Math.random()*(6-1+1)+1);
            second = (int)(Math.random()*(6-1+1)+1);
            third = (int)(Math.random()*(6-1+1)+1);

            System.out.println(first + "\t" + second + "\t" + third + "\t");

            if (first == second || second == third || first == third) 
            {
                rolledDoubles = true; //you rolled a double! This will stop the loop
                System.out.println("Double! It took " + counter + " tries to get it!");
            }

        }
        while(!rolledDoubles); //uses not operator with rolledDoubles so when rolledDoubles is true then we stop the loop, if false we keep going
    }   

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   public class ExtraProblem4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int first, second, third;
        int counter = 0;
        boolean isDoubles= false;
        while (!isDoubles)
        {
            first = (int)(Math.random()*(6-1+1)+1);
            second = (int)(Math.random()*(6-1+1)+1);
            third = (int)(Math.random()*(6-1+1)+1);

            System.out.println(first + "\t" + second + "\t" + third + "\t");
            isDoubles= first == second || first == third || second == third;  
            counter++; 
        }       
        System.out.println("Double! It took " + counter + " tries to get it!");
      }
   }
```